# Cannot patch \document,(auxhook) using \AtBeginDocument instead

Tags: hyperref

When I am executing the TeX file below, the warning:

> Cannot patch \document,(auxhook) using \AtBeginDocument instead.

is given. plz solve this problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{docmute}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you think we can make anything useful out of *I am facing below given problem when executing the Tex file Cannot patch \document,(auxhook) using \AtBeginDocument instead. plz solve this problem*???  Please provide the document that causes this problem

Comment: We are not here to solve your problems, we are here to help you (Ok, mostly the others, but anyway). Solving your problems is your job. If you want us to help with your problem, help us to understand it.

Answer (score 7):

Package `auxhook` provides hooks for writing at the begin of `.aux` files. The typical usage case is providing command definitions (`\providecommand`) to disable commands, when the package, that defines the command, is no longer loaded. Therefore package `auxhook` needs access to the point right after opening the `.aux` files for writing. The main `.aux` file is opened in `\begin{document}`, therefore it tries to patch it. If the patching fails, because `\document` is changed by a class, package, newer LaTeX version or whatever, then it uses the official hook `\AtBeginDocument`. Depending on the used class and packages it might be a little too late. Therefore a warning is given. Probably the warning can be ignored in many or most cases. If you want clarity, then a minimal document for analysis is needed.